# JQuery .load() not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I am using following code for my website:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("img#logo").load(function() {
            alert('Hello');
        });
    });
</script>
```

And this is not working in IE but works fine in Firefox, Chrome and Safari.

Comment: possibly syntax related? looks like `});` is missing after the alert

Comment: no error in syntax I had written wrong here..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can confirm that your code **does** work in IE 8 on windows 7 64 using unminified version:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
<title>test</title>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
     <script>
         $(document).ready(function () {
             console.log($.fn.jquery);
             $("img#logo").load(function () {
                 console.log('Hello');
             });
         });
     </script>
</head> 
 <body> 
     <img id="logo" src="somegig.gif" onload="console.log('load');"/>
 </body>
</html>
```

This will log 1.10.1 then load and then Hello, maybe you have to validate your html and make sure your html is valid maybe that's a problem.

Comment: sorry but again it is not working is there some problem with my IE..?

Comment: @ShardaSingh the problem with IE is basically that is sucks (although it has some perks on a company network) but if you press F12 to open the the developer tools then click on script then click on start debugging then reload the page you'll see the logs. Next time 'not working' isn't good enough, need error or expected output verses actual output.

Answer (score 1):

a quick review of http://api.jquery.com/load-event/ provides some caveats:

> Caveats of the load event when used with images
>
> A common challenge developers attempt to solve using the .load()
>   shortcut is to execute a function when an image (or collection of
>   images) have completely loaded. There are several known caveats with
>   this that should be noted. These are:
>
> - It doesn't work consistently nor reliably cross-browser
> - It doesn't fire correctly in WebKit if the image src is set to the    same src as before
> - It doesn't correctly bubble up the DOM tree
> - Can cease to fire for images that already live in the browser's cache

Note the first and fourth caveats. Clear the cache and try again.

Also, do you need the jQuery migrate ? Lose it and see if it is glitching your IE